# Duplication of message when adding to DB in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

When i try to add one post to db using `wp_insert_post()` in db added two posts:

**Ajax request:**

> /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getchats&chat_type=all-chat&last_msg=110&add_msg=true&chat_message=helloworlds

action for this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getchats', 'getchats'); 

function getchats(){
    if (!isset($_GET['last_msg'])||(!is_numeric($_GET['last_msg'])||(!isset($_GET['chat_type'])))){
        die(json_encode(array('error' => 'no_latest')));
    }
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID($_GET['chat_type']); //the categories name 
    if ((isset($_GET['add_msg']))&&(isset($_GET['chat_message']))){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $description = $_GET['chat_message'];
        $title = $description;
        if (strlen($title)>20){
            $title = mb_substr($title, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $my_post = array(
            'post_content'   => $description,
            'post_title'     =>  $title,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'chatmsg',
            'post_author'    => $user_id,
            'post_category'  => array($cat_id)
        );
        wp_insert_post($my_post);
    }
    $args=array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'category' => $cat_id,
        'post_type' => 'chatmsg',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $messages = [];
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    die(json_encode($posts));
    foreach( $posts as $post ){
        if ($post->ID > $_GET['last_msg']){
        $row = array(
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'message'=>$post->post_content,
            'author'=>$post->post_author,
            'date'=>$post->post_date,

        );
        $message[] = $row;
        }
    }
    die(json_encode(array('error' => 'ok', 'messages'=> $messages)));
}
```

Why am i using only one `wp_insert_post` but receive two post?

UPD: Need use wp_doing_ajax for it. Thanks for answer Maxim Sarandi.

```
if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    add_action('wp_ajax_getchats', 'getchats');     
    function getchats()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11081) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234254/wordpress-wp-insert-post-firing-multiple-times) might help you.

And can i give you a few recommendation to your code style?

First - use $_POST for similar queries.

Second - stop use `die(wp_send_json())`. Inside `wp_send_json` already present `die();` Just use `wp_send_json_error()` for error response or `wp_send_json_success();` or `wp_send_json()`

Third - use `nonces` and `check_ajax_referer();`

Fourth - stop cloning not needed brackets.

Comment: I'm using $_GET only for debug. All data after checking code will send via JSON and POST. For die and other - thanks!